Pygame zero duplicate Actor
So if I have an object:
bomb = Actor("bomb")
Is there a way to draw multiple instances of that object onto the screen, without needing to duplicate it?
I tried using multiple bombs, but thats not what I want. I want it to place a new instance of the bomb if one is already on the screen.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Maybe, but not usually. Typically each thing/object/Actor in a scene is backed by a separate object. That way each can have its own position and state. If you want to associate a bunch of bombs into a group then put each bomb object in a container (list, etc.) to group them together in code, but unless you want each bomb to blow up together and move together or get picked up together it probably makes a lot more sense to make each bomb a separate object.

As mentionend by woodford, you can use a list to keep track of multiple instances of an object (i.e. an Actor in Pygame Zero). Here's a minimal working example that places a bomb wherever you click on the window:
import pgzrun
import random

bombs = []

def draw():
    for bomb in bombs:
        bomb.draw()

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    bomb = Actor("bomb.png")
    bomb.x = pos[0]
    bomb.y = pos[1]
    bombs.append(bomb)

pgzrun.go()


